# solving this Differential Equation (second order,non-homogeneous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''-2y'+2y=\sin{2x}$

The roots are: $1\pm 2i$

General solution for the homogeneous part :

$y(x)=c_1e^x\cos{2x}+c_2e^x\sin(2x)$

$$
\begin{cases}
c_1'(x)e^x\cos(2x)+c_2'(x)\sin(2x)e^x=0\\
c_1'(x)[e^x\cos(2x)-2e^x\sin(2x)]+c_2'(x)[e^x\sin(2x)+2e^x\cos(2x)]=\sin(2x)
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to get $c'_1(x)$ and $c_2'(x)$ , I'm not able to simplify it to the point that the integrand is kinda simple.

Comment: Did you use Cramer's rule to solve for $c_1'(x)$ and $c_2'(x)$? After that, you can use integration by parts to get $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure about the roots ?

Comment: I used the method of variation of parameters. Yes the roots are right

Comment: $x^2-2x+2=0$ has the roots $x = 1 \pm i$.

Comment: :D yup, mybad ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_P=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$$ where $A,B$ are real numbers.

Comment: Can you give me a link of the explanation of the "ansatz" method ?

Comment: see here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A similar example from one of the textbooks will give you guidance on solving the IVP.  The other responder has given a link Please view that too.

[image]

[image]